# Access React context from regular function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Is it possible to access React context from a non-React helper function?

For example, I have a context provider that saves the root slug for a case study page when the app loads. I then need to build URLs, consuming the context provider at various places around my app. So I've created a helper function to do so:

**components/caseStudies/index.jsx**

```
import getCaseStudyPath from '../../lib/helpers/getCaseStudyPath';

const CaseStudies = ({ caseStudy }) => {
  // caseStudy.slug === 'test-case-study'
  const caseStudyPath = getCaseStudyPath(caseStudy.slug);

  return (
    <a href={caseStudyPath}>Test</a>
  );
};
```

**lib/helpers/getCaseStudySlug**

```
export default (slug) => {
  // Get caseStudyRootSlug from React context
  return `/${caseStudyRootSlug}/${slug}`;
  // For example, this returns '/case-studies/test-case-study'
};
```

I know I can just consumer the context provider in my React component, or even as a HOC, and just pass the value to the helper function, but I need to use this helper function throughout my app and don't want the overhead of setting up a consumer every time I want to use it.

Comment: I see here two options: a) use global variable (window), b) use the context hook `useContext`

Comment: @IvanBurnaev I've not come across useContext before. Could you provide any more info on this? Maybe an example or link?

Comment: Here is the official API https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext, and Dan's introduction https://youtu.be/dpw9EHDh2bM. But beware: it's still in alpha version yet.

Comment: @IvanBurnaev Ah right, alpha is no good for me. I'm in production. I'm not too keen on the global window variable either because I don't get any of the benefits of React context then. It's a shame if this isn't currently possible with React context in production because it seems that React context is simply a client store of data, so it would make sense to access it from anywhere in JavaScript.

Comment: It's a bit strange trying to use React context outside React itself =). Your JavaScript function doesn't know anything about React and it's context. So, there is a problem of getting variable and it has not so much options: closure, global variable, param passing. I can't imagine anything else =(

Comment: Yeah I see the problem. Although at the end of the day I'm just storing a plain Javascript object of data in my React context, so other Javascript shouldn't have any problem reading it if it could get access.

Comment: Hooks are officially released in version 16.8 (released Feb. 6) -- they are **not** still in alpha.

Comment: I've just got round to trying useContext and it turns out it only works in a stateless functional component (not a regular JS function like mine). Specifically I get the error `Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.`